# My website keeps loading indefinitely after 3 operations

Tags: javascript, java, sql, jsp, web

i can't understand why my site after 3 operations goes into a literally infinite loop. i am using eclipse and i am hosting the server with tomcat, as database i use workbench. The server initially does not give errors, or so it seems for the first two operations, but then as soon as I perform the third operation the site does not respond and goes into infinite upload (I attach photos and code).

I don't think it's a code problem, maybe it will be Tomcat max cache? I've been banging my head for more than 3 days but I just can't solve it, finally I don't have any kind of error inside the Eclipse console, and the only way to get my site up and running is to totally restart the tomcat server.

[image]

This is my code: https://github.com/Fatted/Olysmart_TSW2021 (download the zip,databse is included)

I already thank those who will help me or who at least had some time to read this post, thanks!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After quick run through the code I think you're experiencing DB connection leak. Each query in your DAOs opens new connection to DB and never closes it. Try using [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) syntax for connections.

Comment: now I try and update you, thank you very much!

Comment: that was just the problem, thank you very much! I don't know how to thank you, it was such a trivial thing that I didn't even think about it. Thank you again